# Jquery ui and mootools issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have used the below lines in my web page

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.2/mootools-yui-compressed.js'></script>
```

From the above lines if I placed the last script line my mootools is not working.

How can I achieve this if am placing the above lines?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at `jQuery.noCoflict();`

#### **[`Official Document`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

> Many JavaScript libraries use `$` as a function or variable name, just as `jQuery` does. In `jQuery's` case, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, so all functionality is available without using `$`. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside `jQuery`, return control of `$` back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`. Old references of `$` are saved during `jQuery` initialization; `noConflict()` simply restores them.